# Using "due to" in a sentence

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

Does this sentence sound right in English?

> You can improve your English due to me.

Is it correct using "due to" in this case?

Comment: It's not considered a strictly improper usage by many nowadays (the 'because of' reading), but I certainly wouldn't be subscribing to a course offered by a prospective tutor advertising themself in this way.

Comment: "Unbelievably, we all passed our English Language A-levels – and this was all due to you" is an acceptable example of the 'because of, subset down to / ascribable to' sense of 'due to'. This might seem to license OP's example, but that sentence is almost completely unidiomatic. "You can all improve your English because of Professor Mandateler" is acceptable; replacing 'because of' with 'due to' is becoming less idiomatic, but is, I'd say, still acceptable. But OP's example is beyond the pale.

Comment: It looks both awkward and *ambiguous* to me. Is the speaker making the point that ***she*** is responsible for fact that the addressee is ***currently*** in a position to improve his command of English (because of things the speaker did in the past)? Or is she saying that ***her future involvement*** would enable the addressee to improve his English (if he so chose)? I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

The expression “due to”, which numerous references claim means *‘caused by’*, refers back to a noun or a pronoun,  i.e. the antecedent.

> 1. The **improvement** in your English is **due to** me.
> 2. The improvement in your English is **caused by** me.

*The Chicago Manual of Style* [says that we use “due to” in place of “attributable to,”](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/because-due-to-since-and-as) but not if it can be replaced with “because of.”

> 1. The improvement in your English is **attributable to** me (Yes)
> 2. The improvement in your English is **due to** me. (Yes)

[*Daily Writing Tips*](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/because-of-and-due-to/) says *“Because of” is an adverb, which means it can only modify verbs, adjectives and clauses, but not nouns and pronouns.*

> 3. You can **improve** your English **because of** me. (Yes)
> 4. You can improve your English **due to** me. (No)

The two-word preposition “because of” can be substituted with “as a result of”

> 5. Your English improved **because of** me. (Yes)
> 6. Your English improved **as a result of** me. (Yes)

In a passive construction, I'd suggest using the preposition *by*

> Your English can be improved **by** me.

The OP can rewrite the original statement, using the present simple or future simple tense, as

> 1. You can improve your English **with my** help/assistance.
> 2. **With my** help/assistance your English will improve.

Comment: I think this has more thorough analysis than previous answers.

Comment: You quote a web page as saying that “because of” is an adverb. As you correctly point out later, it's a preposition. Would it be better to say that a preposition-phrase "because of N" is an adverb-phrase?

Comment: @RosieF I try not to get involved in these types of discussion but speaking for myself I would call "because of N" a prepositional phrase.

Answer (score -1):

The sentence is incorrect. "Due to" means "caused by", but that meaning doesn't suit the sentence you quoted. "Due to" can be used with certain nouns such as "thanks", as in "Thanks are due to XYZ for their good explanation". But "due to" is not used in that way in your sentence either.

Comment: There have been various debunkings of the " 'due to' cannot be used to mean 'because of' " claim on ELU.

Answer (score -3):

"Due to noun/gerund" explains the cause of something. Its synonyms are "because of" and "owning to". I think you should write the sentence as "You can improve your English for me".

Comment: I think your "owning to" is a typo for "owing to", which indeed is a synonym of "because of". But "due to" is not.

Comment: I'm not sure that "You can improve your English for me" would be taken as having the same meaning as "You can improve your English due to me."